# How to write any number of elements of a list in one line in a CSV file?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, char, training-data

I want to write a CSV file with a specific format, so I can train with the data. I need every information per input in one line. The charList is a list of chars (with length 108) in ascii numbers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8DmU.png)

Instead of put the list in the csv, I want to have every char seperately.
So one CSV line should look like:

0.2344,0.234565,0.245534,45,27,34...34

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: you show expected result but you didn't show what you data you try to save. And we can't read in your mind.

Comment: if you want list as separated element then you have to write code to `flatten` list - convert `[1, ["A", "B"], 2]` into `[1, "A", "B", 2]`. You could use `+` like `data[:1] + data[1] + data[2:]`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show example input data and what result you get at this moment so I will use my data.

---

You have to `flatten` it. You can use `+` to join lists

If you have

```
data = [12, 34, ["A", "B"], 56]
```

where `data[2]` is `["A", "B"]`
then

```
result = data[:2] + data[2] + data[3:]
```

gives

```
[12, 34, "A", "B", 56]
```

---

If you have

```
data = [12, 34, "AB", 56]
```

then you can use `list` to convert string into list

```
result = data[:2] + list(data[2]) + data[3:]
```